# How to add application shortcuts to the Windows 10 Links Toolbar?

Tags: windows-10, shortcuts, file-shortcut

A few years ago I was somehow able to add application shortcuts (Chrome, Notepad, Windows Explorer, etc) to my **Toolbar Links in Windows 10**. (Please do not confuse this with the taskbar, which is easy to add app shortcuts to.) I have a new PC now and I cannot remember or figure out how to add application shortcuts to the Links Toolbar.

Just so we're on the same page, the Links Toolbar is hidden by default, but can be made visible by right-clicking in the taskbar area and selecting Toolbars->Links. Then you can unlock the taskbar and add application shortcuts to the links toolbar - but I cannot figure out how to do it.

I'm sitting here looking at the perfectly configured Link Toolbar shortcuts on my OLD PC:

[image]

Notice Chrome, Notepad, Windows Explorer, SSMS, VS, Email.

But on my NEW PC I cannot figure out how to add those same shortcuts. Still Windows 10, same OS. It seems before I was able to drag/drop those shortcuts onto that, but I'm unable to do that now. I can easily drag/drop onto the taskbar, but not onto my visible and unlocked links toolbar.

You ask WHY NOT just use the taskbar? I like the links toolbar better because (1) I can get smaller icons on there and (2) the behavior is better and different - when I click, it simply launches the app, or a 2nd/3rd instance - the taskbar assumes I don't want a new instance when I click on an app shortcut for an app that is already open.

How can application shortcuts be added to the Links Toolbar in Windows 10 Pro? (latest update version as of April 13, 2019)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drag & drop should work, *if you unlock the Taskbar first*.

Otherwise, you should be able to add application shortcuts to the source folder:

```
C:\users\<username>\favorites\Links
```

Keith

Comment: Drag-drop doesn't seem to work, but your path works. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Thanks for the feedback & marking reply as 'Answer'.